# GStream Meson installation not working with omx plugin

Tags: gstreamer, meson-build

I'm trying to install GStreamer using [meson](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build) and I want to install one of its plugins: omx. For that, I set it to `enabled` in [meson_options.txt](http://option(%27omx%27,%20type%20:%20%27feature%27,%20value%20:%20%27disabled%27)) file and add the target value with:

```
option('target', type : 'combo',
    choices : ['none', 'generic', 'rpi', 'bellagio', 'tizonia', 'zynqultrascaleplus'], value : 'rpi',
    description : 'The OMX platform to target')
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
subprojects/gst-omx/meson.build:220:2: ERROR: Problem encountered: Unsupported omx target specified. Use the -Dtarget option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change meson_options.txt files, build options should be set with **-D optname=optval** in command line when you setup meson build directory, and to change value in subproject prefix with subproject name with colon: **-D subproject:optname=optval**, thus:

```
meson build -D omx=enabled -D gst-omx:target=rpi
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. It's working now.